# npm throwing error in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Following is my code in which npm is throwing error. Earlier it was working fine, but when I have copied the same code in different directory, ran npm install and now trying to run npm start. It is throwing error :

```
ERROR in ./www/plugins/entry.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:8)

5 | import routes from './routes/routes'
6 | 
> 7 | render((<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />),document.getElementById('app'))
```

Code is :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router , browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import routes from './routes/routes';

render((<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />), document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "userapp3",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack --config www/server/webpack.js --watch --colors",
  "webp": "concurrently 'node www/server/index.js' 'webpack --config www/server/webpack.js --watch --colors'",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
  "minifier": "^0.8.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
  "react": "^15.2.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
  "react-helmet": "^3.3.0",
  "react-router": "^2.5.2",
  "react-select2": "^4.0.1",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
  "webpack": "^1.13.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have babel set up and configured to transpile JSX?

Comment: I have added package.json

Comment: How have you configured you webpack. Can you share that

Comment: Its done. I missed .babelrc file, but during npm install it should have come.